# Can't access iterated data outside of for loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop

I've got a number of `li` each containing `<img>`tags.

```
<li class="pic"><img src="pic_1.jpg"></li>
<li class="pic"><img src="pic_2.jpg"></li>
<li class="pic"><img src="pic_3.jpg"></li>
<li class="pic"><img src="pic_4.jpg"></li>
```

A simple for loop that iterates through the list items finds the native widths of all of the images - and yes, I'm aware of jQuery `.each` function can do this also.  Credit for the code to find the native width (and height) should go to [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/get-an-images-native-width/).

```
picarray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < $('.pic').length; i++) {
    var theimg = new Image();
    theimg.src = $('.pic img').eq(i).attr('src');
    var picW = theimg.width;
    picarray = [picW];

    console.log(picW);
    console.log(picarray);
};

console.log(picarray[3]);
```

What I'd like to do is take the iterated data and dump in into an array which I can then access outside of the for loop.  I think I've created a global variable, `picarray` at the top of js to do this, but when I test the code out the array comes out fine within the loop but when I test and try to access a specific item within the array, outside of the loop I just get `undefined` in the console panel.

How can I put the iterated data that the for loop spits out into and array that I can then access from outside of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing the right way. Each iteration is overwriting the array and the total length is only 1.

```
<script>
picarray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < $('.pic').length; i++) {
    var theimg = new Image();
    theimg.src = $('.pic img').eq(i).attr('src');
    var picW = theimg.width;
    picarray[i] = picW;

    console.log(picW);
    console.log(picarray);
};

console.log(picarray);

</script>
```

Comment: Nice work!  That's just the result I was looking for!! Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the array with a new array that has  length of 1 on each iteration. Thus at the end you are only left with the value of the last image in the array

Change:

```
picarray = [picW]; // reassigns whole variable with a new array each iteration
```

To

```
picarray.push(picW); // adds to existing array instead
```

Comment: Oh I see!  So every time the loop runs, picarray = [picW] just changes the value of picarray, as opposed to creating an array that looks something like picarray = [150, 200, 345, etc, etc]

Comment: I've done that thanks and see it works!  There isn't a way to creating the array once the for loop has finished looping through all of the list items is there?

Comment: See Arnal's answer @charlietfl, that's what I was looking for

Comment: resultant array will be the same either way. Indexing will be exactly the same using `push()`

Comment: Thats true, but .push seems to rewrite the array every time the loop runs.  What I wanted was a way to run the loop on the x number of list items and place the data it returns into an array ONCE the loop has stopped running

Comment: that doesn't make much sense to me but whatever works for you

Answer (score 0):

you create a new array every time through the loop, so picarray always has only one value - change picarray = [picW] to picarray.push(picW)

Answer (score 0):

If you code should gather all the pictures into array:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  var picarray = [];

  $('.pic > img').each(function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $(this).attr('src');
    picarray.push(img);
  });
      
  alert('Thrid image source = ' + picarray[3].width);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<li class="pic"><img src="http://www.tnetnoc.com//hotelphotos/816/41816/2241284-Hotel-Sacher-Wien-Hotel-Exterior-1-DEF.jpg" height="60" width="60"></li>
    <li class="pic"><img src="http://www.tnetnoc.com//hotelphotos/816/41816/2241284-Hotel-Sacher-Wien-Hotel-Exterior-2-DEF.jpg" height="60" width="60"></li>
    <li class="pic"><img src="http://www.tnetnoc.com//hotelphotos/816/41816/2241284-Hotel-Sacher-Wien-Hotel-Exterior-3-DEF.jpg" height="60" width="60"></li>
    <li class="pic"><img src="http://www.tnetnoc.com//hotelphotos/816/41816/2241284-Hotel-Sacher-Wien-Lobby-1-DEF.jpg" height="60" width="60"></li>
```

Comment: OP is pushing widths, not elements into array

Comment: I did see that, but I am not sure why? The width could be obtained from the img object

Comment: Why would I want to get the images src and put them into an array?  I'm wanting to find the images native width and heights so that I can run the array through another for loop and apply resizing code to each img

Comment: From your code it looks you read the image width from the img object. The only one thing set in that object is src. So if I got the image object I can alway get the image width by picarray[3].width